# Unable to build JBoss

Tags: java, jboss

I'm trying to run `build.sh` in the build folder of jboss-5.1.0.GA-src.

The build fails with the message:

```
_default:compile-classes:
    [javac] Compiling 4 source files to /home/yyi4492/jboss-5.1.0.GA-src/messaging/output/classes
warning: [options] source value 1.5 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] target value 1.5 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
/home/yyi4492/jboss-5.1.0.GA-src/messaging/src/main/org/jboss/mq/server/jmx/Queue.java:64: error: cannot access Service
        delegate.addNotificationListener(listener, filter, handback);
                ^
  class file for org.jboss.system.Service not found
1 error
3 warnings
```

I'm using Jdk 1.8.0_144 as JAVA_HOME.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try JDK 6 for build as jboss-5.1.0.GA is too older version and it might not support JDK 8.